# Function to test if a string is a palindrome

Tags: python, string

My goal is to write a code that checks if a given string is a palindrome (same word forwards and backwards) and so far I have this

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    string = s
    if (string==string[::-1]):
        print("The string IS a palindrome")
    else:
        print("The string is NOT a palindrome")
    return
```

When I run these two asserts however, it only types out "The string IS a palindrome" once for the first assert and not "The string is NOT a palindrome" for the assert with 'house'

```
assert is_palindrome('noon')
assert not is_palindrome('house')
```

So for some reason that I can't see it must be only executing the function once.
Can someone help me by telling me where the problem is?

Comment: Your function returns `None`

Comment: You also don't need the `string = s`, you can use `s` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the return value of your function is always `None`, so the `assert is_palindrome(...)` will fail and raise an `AssertionError`. Any statement following this (in this case your `assert not is_palindrome('house')`) will not be executed.

What you need to do is return an appropriate value.  For example:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    string = s
    if (string==string[::-1]):
        print("The string IS a palindrome")
        return True
    else:
        print("The string is NOT a palindrome")
        return False
```

Comment: Can even get rid of `else` because of early return.

Comment: @MarioIshac Yes, you can get rid of the `else`. Whether to do so or not is a stylistic decision, and personally I think it is clearer with the `else` still there.

Comment: Yes, now it worked! What is the logic behind this? I thought I already said that if it is a palindrome write this, if not write this and then return to do it for as many times as needed. What does return True/False do?

Comment: @DQuijote It will use the relevant boolean value (`True` or `False`) as the return value of the function, and return control back to the caller. The `assert` in the caller will test for this and if the value is false (which in fact includes various other values that are treated as false, e.g. `0`, but here we are actually using `False`) then you get the `AssertionError` that I mentioned.  In your code you were just printing a human-readable message but not doing anything that would control the behaviour of the `assert`.

Answer (score -2):

What are you asserting when you say `assert is_palindrome('noon')`

Your function returns `None`, if you assert that you won't get any error `assert is_palindrome('noon')==None`

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    string = s
    if (string==string[::-1]):
        print("The string IS a palindrome")
        return True
    else:
        print("The string is NOT a palindrome")
        return False

assert is_palindrome('noon')
assert not is_palindrome('house')
assert is_palindrome('house')
```